# BigQuery UI - How to schedule a query to run on the last day of the month?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query that pulls a summary of metrics for the past month that needs to run on the last day of each month at a set time.

The BigQuery 'Schedule query' UI allows you to choose a date and time to run a query each month but there is no apparent option to choose that last day of the month.

If I simply choose the 31st of the month, what happens if there are only 30-days in that month? Will the query still run?

Or do I have to schedule a query to run on the 27th, 28th, 29th, 30th, 31st of the month to make sure that I don't miss the correct date?

I can't find any mention of this situation in the BigQuery documentation or online so any help/suggestions will be very gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you need to run your query in the last day of each month. However, if you set 31st of the month as the [schedule options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query), it will skip the months which do not have 31 days.

You can check this affirmation, by performing the following test in the BigQuery UI:

1. In the Schedule query options, under Schedule options, set:

   - **Repeats**: Monthly
   - **On the**: 31
   - **Start date and run time**: set the date to 10th of June (which is a month with 30 days)
2. Click **Schedule**
3. On the left side of the BigQuery UI, click on **Scheduled queries**
4. Check the query you saved. Among other details, it should be displayed **Next Scheduled**.
5. It will be shown July, 31

As you can see, it skipped the *30th of June*. Thus, when you configure your query to run on the 31st of each month, it will ignore the months with less than 31 days. For this reason, I would advise you to select 27th, 28th, 29th, 30th, 31st of each month in order to run it in a manner that suits you.

*As a bonus information, you can set up a [Custom schedule option](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries?_ga=2.140736882.-1753417650.1585809226&_gac=1.40125078.1587363424.EAIaIQobChMIu5LPwqz26AIVGOJ3Ch3aigJ4EAAYASAAEgLRm_D_BwE#setting_up_a_scheduled_query), as mentioned here. You can use syntaxes as "1st monday of month 00:00" or "every monday 00:00", [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#formatting_the_schedule).*